# Литература по SQL

Tags: sql

Посоветуйте качественную литературу по SQL (желательно без привязки к конкретной платформе). Интересует именно доходчивое разъяснение на примерах возможностей SQL.

Читал Gruber "Understanding SQL", книга отличная, но с кучей опечаток, и слишком устарела по версиям SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Я как-то давно упражнялся в SQL на [www.sql-ex.ru](http://www.sql-ex.ru/). У них можно решать задачки, запросы автоматически проверяется на SQL Server 2000/2005.

Comment: Уже SQL Server 2008 R2 плюс MySQL плюс PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

[Учебник по SQL](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/)

Answer (score 2):

- O'Reilly: [SQL In A Nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565927445.do), [Learning SQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007270.do), [SQL Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009762.do)
- Stephane Faroult, [The Art of SQL](http://www.amazon.com/Art-SQL-Stephane-Faroult/dp/0596008945)
- его же [Refactoring SQL Applications](http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-SQL-Applications-Stephane-Faroult/dp/0596514972) (ну эт попозже)

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от ваших познаний.
Я начинал с SQL для чайников.
Потом привязался к FireBird и начал читать только по ней.

Answer (score 0):

В университете преподы материал давали по "Введение в системы баз данных. Дейт"
(Introduction to Database Systems, C.J. Date ). В 1996 я бы за эту книгу убить мог :).  Это исчерпывающий теоретический материал. 
Ну а далее можно использовать справочники по конкретной СУБД.